# Check if service is installed, if yes obtain status and generate a report - using Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, yaml, rhel

A newbie to ansible. I need to check if services/daemons are running (Windows and Linux) using ansible. Will be having separate yaml files for Windows and Linux. So I need to:

1. Check if the service exists
2. If it does, get the status
3. Export the result to a file/report/csv

For **Windows**, can this be a workable sample of a playbook since there are multiple services to be checked and result to be captured :

```
- name: "check status of services"
  win_service:
    name: 
        - service1
        - service2
        - service3
  register: result
  failed_when: result is not defined
```

For **Linux**, I have put together a playbook to see if the service exists and is running:

```
---

  - name: Gathering service facts
      service_facts:
      register: services_state

  - name: Service1 status
      service_facts:
  - debug:
      msg: Service1 is installed
    when:
      - ansible_facts.services['Service1.service'] is defined
      msg: Service1 is running
    when:
      - services_state.ansible_facts.services["Service1.service"].state is running

  - name: Service2 status
      service_facts:
  - debug:
      msg: Service2 is installed
    when:
      - ansible_facts.services['Service2.service'] is defined
      msg: Service2 is running
    when:
      - services_state.ansible_facts.services["Service2.service"].state is running

  - name: Service3 status
      service_facts:
  - debug:
      msg: Service3 is installed
    when:
      - ansible_facts.services['Service3.service'] is defined
      msg: Service3 is running
    when:
      - services_state.ansible_facts.services["Service3.service"].state is running
```

Can you help with the playbooks/ymls for both the Operating systems please?

Also, for both, I need to redirect and the output to a file to make a report since the playbooks will be run on multiple servers

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html

Comment: thanks @Zeitounator. Needed some examples. The ones in the page didnt help me with how to use the output and also need to use it to feed a report

Answer (score 0):

Please explore **win_service** ansible module to verify status of services in remote windows server and register the output into to a var

**Reference Doc:** https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_service_module.html

```
- name: "check status of test-service"
  win_service:
    name: test-service
  register: result
  failed_when: result is not defined

- name: "print status of service"
  debug: 
    var: result
```

when you debug the output of a windows service status in ansible, you get an output which looks something like this:

```
ok: [10.xx.xx.xx] => {
    "result": {
        "can_pause_and_continue": false,
        "changed": false,
        "depended_by": [],
        "dependencies": [],
        "description": "test-service service",
        "desktop_interact": false,
        "display_name": "test-service",
        "exists": true,
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "name": "test-service",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\justlearning\\test-service.exe",
        "start_mode": "auto",
        "state": "running",
        "username": ".\\justlearning"
    }
}
```

you could print this status into a file and copy it into the same remote server. Have a file named **service_status.txt** in your **ansible host machine** and have a variable **'{{ result }}'** in it and copy using **win_copy** ansible module

**Reference Doc:** https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_copy_module.html

So your next task in your playbook will look like something like this:

```
- name: copy service status file to server
  win_copy:
    src: /Users/justlearning/Downloads/service_status.txt
    dest: C:\tmp\
```

Similarly, you will have a module for handling **systemd** services in linux or the normal **service** module itself and also a **copy** module for linux

**Reference Docs:**

```
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html
```

Comment: thanks @jithendra-baswareddy. I have edited the original post to add some detail based on your input for windows. Can you let me know if that is workable?

Comment: you can loop through different services using ```with_items```. Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/items.html

Comment: thanks. figured out a way to do it using set_fact as well